# Index Size not reachable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have created a non-clustered index on table columns and it contains 5GB of index data but I am not able to see this +5GB data size change on my disk.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you see it on the disk?  The index is in the database.

Comment: If your data file(s) had 5+ GB of free space, they would not need to grow and the file size(s) would remain the same.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, lets say my mdf and ldf are on F disk, now I have 15gb of free space on disk. After I had created index of 5GB, then size will not change?

Comment: No not necessarily.  SQL grabs more disk space than it needs, and doesn't grab more until it needs it, and then again it grabs more than it needs.  Otherwise it would be growing every time it needed the slightest bit more space.  It prefers to grow less frequently, in big chunks.

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks I got it! also check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how much space is being used within a SQL mdf or ndf file with this query:

```
SELECT  df.name ,
        df.size / 128 AS FileSize ,
        df.size / 128 - fsu.unallocated_extent_page_count / 128 AS UsedSpace
FROM    DatabaseName.sys.dm_db_file_space_usage fsu
        INNER JOIN DatabaseName.sys.database_files df ON fsu.file_id = df.file_id
```

If the file had enough free space before, it would not have to grow when you created the index.